# proxy to check if transit network packet is udp or tcp

Tags: python, proxy

I have a situation where i need to setup a proxy which can test if packet in going through it is `udp` or `tcp`.

I need to setup a very lightweight proxy. Any idea or suggestion which network analyzer can help in doing so?

Setup would be like as follow

```
Service running on server ====> Proxy[to be developed] ===> Internet [Outside world]
                         <=====                       <=====
```

I have gone through basic kind of proxy setting in python as follows

```
import urllib2

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://61.233.25.166:80"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
print html
```

Any suggestions how can i monitor if network packet going through my proxy is `UDP` or `TCP` or any other protocol like `RTP`

Comment: When the proxy listens to a socket, it has to *tell* the system which protocol it wants - if it is UDP or TCP. HTTP is a TCP protocol. So distinguishing the two packets seems a non-issue to me.

Comment: To be precise: if you setup a proxy for both TCP and UDP, there is **no way** you can do it with a single socket (unless you go lower level and do your own protocol decode from IP up). You will need to open one TCP listening socket and one UDP listening socket, and check both explicitly. Even those libraries that wrap this in syntactic sugar will still require you to effect two calls and manage two very distinct objects, no matter that the managing code will then be the same. Can you detail exactly *what you were told, and why*?

Comment: In order to understand well what is said above, take a look to the OSI model : http://f.tqn.com/y/compnetworking/1/S/g/basics_osimodel.jpg
The socket is the result of an abstraction of the layers 1, 2, 3 and 4. This is why you need to be explicit at the creation of your socket and tell if it's a TCP based protocol or an UDP based protocol (in order to configure the layer 4)

Comment: Don't consider the outbound traffic from specific port, consider the nginx proxy pass which routes the traffic to my internal services whith their respective ports, ports are forwarded to listen both tcp/udp traffic.